# Compare 2 dataframes for equality in R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, equality

I have 2 dataframes with 2 same columns. I want to check if the datasets are identical. The original datasets have some 700K records but I'm trying to figure out a way to do it using dummy datasets

I tried using compare, identical, all, all_equal etc. None of them returns me True.

The dummy datasets are -

```
a <- data.frame(x = 1:10, b = 20:11)
c <- data.frame(x = 10:1, b = 11:20)

all(a==c)
[1] FALSE

compare(a,c)
FALSE [FALSE, FALSE]

identical(a,c)
[1] FALSE

 all.equal(a,c)
[1] "Component “x”: Mean relative difference: 0.9090909" "Component “b”: Mean relative difference: 0.3225806"
```

The datasets are entirely same, except for the order of the records. If these functions only work when the datasets are mirror images of each other, then I must try something else. If  that is the case, can someone help with how do I get True for these 2 datasets (unordered)

Comment: Is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568991/compare-2-dataframes-for-equality-in-r/56569141#comment99717495_56569141) by user @Gregor right? Would you want `X` and `Z` to be **not** equal?

Comment: Yes, I would not want x and z to be equal. I just want to compare the dataframes for same records irrespective of their order. What lapply sort is doing is it's changing the dataset records itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dplyr`'s `setdiff` works on data frames, I would suggest

```
library(dplyr)
nrow(setdiff(a, c)) == 0 & nrow(setdiff(c, a)) == 0
# [1] TRUE
```

Note that this will **not account for number of duplicate rows**. (i.e., if `a` has multiple copies of a row, and `c` has only one copy of that row, it will still return `TRUE`). Not sure how you want duplicate rows handled...

If you do care about having the same number of duplicates, then I would suggest two possibilities: (a) adding an ID column to differentiate the duplicates and using the approach above, or (b) sorting, resetting the row names (annoyingly), and using `identical`.

**(a)** adding an ID column

```
library(dplyr)
a_id = group_by_all(a) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
c_id = group_by_all(c) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
nrow(setdiff(a_id, c_id)) == 0 & nrow(setdiff(c_id, a_id)) == 0
# [1] TRUE
```

**(b)** sorting

```
a_sort = a[do.call(order, a), ]
row.names(a_sort) = NULL
c_sort = c[do.call(order, c), ]
row.names(c_sort) = NULL
identical(a_sort, c_sort)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a function to sort the columns before comparison is what you need. But it will be slow on large dataframes.

```
unordered_equal <- function(X, Y, exact = FALSE){
  X[] <- lapply(X, sort)
  Y[] <- lapply(Y, sort)
  if(exact) identical(X, Y) else all.equal(X, Y)
}

unordered_equal(a, c)
#[1] TRUE
unordered_equal(a, c, TRUE)
#[1] TRUE

a$x <- a$x + .Machine$double.eps
unordered_equal(a, c)
#[1] TRUE
unordered_equal(a, c, TRUE)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: `lapply(X, sort)` will sort the columns independently, which seems bad. Given `X = data.frame(1:2, 1:2)`, `Y = data.frame(2:1, 2:1)`, `Z = data.frame(1:2, 2:1)`, I *think* OP would want TRUE for X and Y but FALSE for X and Z, but this would say TRUE for all pairs.

Comment: If you use `do.call(order, X)` etc. it will order the rows by all columns.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, I hadn't thought of that. I have asked the OP in a comment to the question if this is what is expected.

Comment: @Gregor, do.call(order, X) doesn't seem to work the way we would want it to. x  = data.frame(1:2, 2:1), do.call(order,x) gives an object with 2 values, (1,2)

Comment: Yes `do.call(order, x)` gives the row order, so to actually reorder the data frame `x[do.call(order, x), ]` as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want may be to compare the ordered underlying matrices.

```
all.equal(matrix(unlist(a[order(a[1]), ]), dim(a)),
          matrix(unlist(c[order(c[1]), ]), dim(c)))
# [1] TRUE
identical(matrix(unlist(a[order(a[1]), ]), dim(a)),
          matrix(unlist(c[order(c[1]), ]), dim(c)))
# [1] TRUE
```

You could wrap this into a function for more convenience:

```
om <- function(d) matrix(unlist(d[order(d[1]), ]), dim(d))

all.equal(om(a), om(c))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new package called waldo

```
library(waldo)
a <- data.frame(x = 1:10, b = 20:11)
c <- data.frame(x = 10:1, b = 11:20)

compare(a,c)
```

And you get:

```
`old$x`: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and 9 more...
`new$x`:                   10           ...

`old$b`: 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 and 9 more...
`new$b`:
```