# Data manipulation - filter function (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to clean up my data based on the inclusion and exclusion criteria. Both indexing and filter function give me 3787 observations of 32 variables. But, when I check using identical() or all.equal(), they are not the same. What am I missing here? I assume this is something to do with filter(). It took me a while to figure out that I had to explicitly state the NA's in filter().

Is it something related to   "filter() only includes rows where the condition is TRUE; it excludes both FALSE and NA values. If you want to preserve missing values, ask for them explicitly..." https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3196

```
analysis1 <- nhanes[(nhanes$Age >= 30 & nhanes$Age <= 79) &
                      !(nhanes$Cancer == 1 | nhanes$Cancer == 7 | nhanes$Cancer == 9) &
                      !(nhanes$Sex == 1 & (nhanes$WTkg > 160 | nhanes$WTkg < 50)) &
                      !(nhanes$Sex == 2 & (nhanes$WTkg > 150 | nhanes$WTkg < 45)) &
                      !(nhanes$HTcm > 190),]


nhanes1 <- nhanes %>%
  filter((is.na(Age) | (Age >= 30 & Age <= 79 )) &
         ((is.na(Cancer) | !(Cancer == 1 | Cancer == 7 | Cancer == 9))) &
         ((is.na(Sex & WTkg) | !(Sex == 1 & (WTkg > 160 | WTkg < 50)))) &
         ((is.na(Sex & WTkg) | !(Sex == 2 & (WTkg > 150 | WTkg < 45)))) &
         ((is.na(HTcm) | !(HTcm > 190))))

identical(analysis1, nhanes1)
all.equal(analysis1, nhanes1)
```

Output:

```
[1] FALSE
 [1] "Attributes: < Component “row.names”: Modes: character, numeric >"              
 [2] "Attributes: < Component “row.names”: target is character, current is numeric >"
 [3] "Component “ID”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"            
 [4] "Component “WBC”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 334 in current 373 in target"         
 [5] "Component “RBC”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 334 in current 373 in target"         
 [6] "Component “HGB”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 334 in current 373 in target"         
 [7] "Component “HCT”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 334 in current 373 in target"         
 [8] "Component “MCV”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 334 in current 373 in target"         
 [9] "Component “MCH”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 334 in current 373 in target"         
[10] "Component “HbA1c”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 340 in current 379 in target"       
[11] "Component “HDL”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 394 in current 433 in target"         
[12] "Component “CRP”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 408 in current 446 in target"         
[13] "Component “TCHOL”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 394 in current 433 in target"       
[14] "Component “TRIG”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 2141 in current 2163 in target"      
[15] "Component “LDL”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 2161 in current 2183 in target"       
[16] "Component “Sex”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"           
[17] "Component “Age”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"           
[18] "Component “Race2”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"         
[19] "Component “Mstatus”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"       
[20] "Component “Fpoverty”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 542 in current 698 in target"    
[21] "Component “Income”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 390 in current 556 in target"      
[22] "Component “WTkg”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 223 in current 229 in target"        
[23] "Component “HTcm”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 225 in current 229 in target"        
[24] "Component “WAISTcm”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 370 in current 376 in target"     
[25] "Component “HIPcm”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 362 in current 368 in target"       
[26] "Component “SBP”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 438 in current 470 in target"         
[27] "Component “DBP”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 438 in current 470 in target"         
[28] "Component “CHF”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"           
[29] "Component “CHD”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"           
[30] "Component “MI”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"            
[31] "Component “Stroke”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"        
[32] "Component “COPD”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"          
[33] "Component “Cancer”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 229 in target"
```

There is some issue with data. If I check the correlation coefficients between the same variables in both datasets, they differ.

```
res_cor <- analysis1 %>% 
  cor_mat(Income, HGB, HCT, MCV, CRP, HDL, LDL, method = "spearman")
res_cor

res_cor1 <- nhanes1 %>% 
  cor_mat(Income, HGB, HCT, MCV, CRP, HDL, LDL, method = "spearman")
res_cor1
```

Output:

```
rowname
<chr>
            Income  HGB    HCT   MCV     CRP     HDL      LDL
             <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>

1   Income  1.000  0.055  0.039 -0.060  -0.150  0.087   0.014
2   HGB     0.055  1.000  0.970 0.220   -0.120  -0.250  0.120
3   HCT    0.039    0.970   1.000   0.180   -0.097  -0.230  0.130
4   MCV   -0.060    0.220   0.180   1.000   -0.150  0.150   -0.022
5   CRP   -0.150    -0.120  -0.097  -0.150  1.000   -0.200  0.074
6   HDL    0.087    -0.250  -0.230  0.150   -0.200  1.000   -0.011
7   LDL    0.014    0.120   0.130   -0.022  0.074   -0.011  1.000

rowname
<chr>
             Income  HGB    HCT   MCV     CRP     HDL      LDL
             <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1   Income  1.000   0.052   0.035   -0.057  -0.150  0.0910  0.0130
2   HGB     0.052   1.000   0.970   0.220   -0.120  -0.2500 0.1200
3   HCT     0.035   0.970   1.000   0.180   -0.099  -0.2300 0.1200
4   MCV    -0.057   0.220   0.180   1.000   -0.150  0.1500  -0.0230
5   CRP    -0.150   -0.120  -0.099  -0.150  1.000   -0.2000 0.0760
6   HDL     0.091   -0.250  -0.230  0.150   -0.200  1.0000  -0.0078
7   LDL     0.013   0.120   0.120   -0.023  0.076   -0.0078 1.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Sort the columns first and then use `identical`: Here is an example with the mtcars dataset with and without sorted data:

Alternatively you can use `setidff` as proposed by @Gregor Thomas here [Compare 2 dataframes for equality in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568991/compare-2-dataframes-for-equality-in-r)

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
  arrange(cyl)
identical(mtcars, mtcars)
identical(mtcars1, mtcars)


library(dplyr)
nrow(setdiff(mtcars, mtcars1)) == 0 & nrow(setdiff(mtcars1, mtcars)) == 0
```

```
> identical(mtcars, mtcars)
[1] TRUE
> mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
+   arrange(cyl)
> identical(mtcars1, mtcars)
[1] FALSE
> nrow(setdiff(mtcars, mtcars1)) == 0 & nrow(setdiff(mtcars1, mtcars)) == 0
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I tried doing that. Added `arrange(ID)` at the end of filter(). Still getting "FALSE" for the `nrow(setdiff(analysis1, nhanes1)) == 0 & nrow(setdiff(nhanes1, analysis1)) == 0`